# remove subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with one column, and I need to get all duplicated lines. This is table:

```
|  name  |
|  ----- |
|    a   |
|    a   |
|    b   |
|    c   |
|    c   |
|    d   |
```

And this is expected result set:

```
|  name  |
|  ----- |
|    a   |
|    a   |
|    c   |
|    c   |
```

I already do this that way:

```
 SELECT t.name FROM my_table t inner join (
        SELECT name, count(1) AS count FROM my_table t2 GROUP BY t2.name HAVING count > 1
      ) AS t1 on t1.name = t.name
```

Is it possible to do it without subquery?

Comment: can I write subquery in where condition ?

Comment: Note that the absence of a PRIMARY KEY may prove problematic further down the road.

Comment: @krishn patel have no idea how to do it without 2 subqueries.

Comment: it will need single sub query. if you want I can write it.

Comment: ok, please do it, any decisions will be interested for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one column, wouldn't this output do?

```
select name, count(*) as num_duplicates
from t
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

This produces one row per name with the number of duplicates. If you have only one column, that seems like a *better* output (to me) than the list of names repeated.

Comment: if you do it. it will bring single time a c not  a a c c

Answer (score 1):

you need to first bring name of having count >1

```
select * from my_table where name in 
(select name from my_table having count(name) > 1 group by name )
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. But actually this is same as my example, but work much more slower